# Breadth First Search Algorithm Does Not Work Results in Infinite Loop

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph, artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search

I am trying to do a BFS search where I dynamically create the Nodes of the graph as I search the State Space. I followed the book but it does not work the frontier keeps on running and the explored set stays at the start value only. Please help, I have been stuck here for 4 days. Still a beginner programmer.

**Problem Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    internal class Problem
    {
        public State start { get; set; }
        public State end { get; set; }

        public string[] action = { "UP", "LEFT", "DOWN", "RIGHT" };

        public Problem(State x, State y)
        {
            start = x;
            end = y;
        }

        public State Result(State s , string a)
        {
            State up;

            if (a == "UP" && s.X - 1 >= 0)
            {
                 up = new State(s.X - 1, s.Y);
               
            }
            else if (a == "LEFT" && s.Y - 1 >= 0)
            {
                up = new State(s.X, s.Y-1);
                
            }
            else if (a == "DOWN" && s.X + 1 <  5)
            {
                up = new State(s.X, s.Y+1);
               
            }
            else if( a == "RIGHT" && s.Y + 1 < 11)
            {
                up = new State(s.X + 1, s.Y);
                
            }
           
            return up;

           
        } 
    
        public bool GoalTest(Node<State> goal)
        {
            if (goal.Data.Equals(end))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    
    }
}
```

**Search Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    internal class Search
    {
        public void BFS(Problem p)
        {
            Queue<Node<State>> frontier = new Queue<Node<State>>();
            HashSet<string> explored = new HashSet<string>();
            List<Node<State>> nNodes = new List<Node<State>>();

            Node<State> root = new Node<State>() {Data = p.start,};
            frontier.Enqueue(root);

            while(frontier.Count > 0)
            {
                Node<State> next = frontier.Dequeue();
                if(!explored.Add(next.Data.Data)) continue;
               

                next.Children = new List<Node<State>>();
                foreach(string action in p.action)
                {
                    next.Children.Add(new Node<State>() { Data = p.Result(next.Data, action), Parent = next });
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < next.Children.Count; i++)
                {
                    
                        if (p.GoalTest(next.Children[i]) == true)
                        {
                            //Solution(next.Children[i]);
                            break;
                        }
                        frontier.Enqueue(next.Children[i]);
                    
                }
            }
        }

        public void Solution(Node<State> n)
        {
            while(n.Parent != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n.Parent.Data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Node Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    internal class Node<T>
    {
        public T Data { get; set; }
        public Node<T>? Parent { get; set; }
        public List<Node<T>> Children { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**State Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    internal class State
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; }

        public State(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Data = $"{X}-{Y}";
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Program**

```
using Test;

State start = new State(0, 1);
State end = new State(3, 7);

Problem p = new Problem(start, end);

Search s = new Search();
s.BFS(p);
```

This is actually for my assignment hence I named it test.
**I am trying to implement the pseudocode from here: (Page 82)**
https://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs470/materials/aima2010.pdf

**Update**
It does not stuck now but it does not input anything into the console after the loop runs it is supposed to get the links between the goal node and the start node via the **"Parent property"**.

Comment: `return up = s;` This overwrites `up` with `s` and then returns it - thus discarding any value that was previously assigned to `up`. Is this really what you intended?

Comment: Oh no. I was playing around with the code since it was giving me a null exception. I changed it but still am getting error.

Comment: "I'm getting an error" is not a sufficiently detailed description of what happened.  Please always provide the exact error text of an error message when asking for help.  An error would be dramatically different behaviour from "keeps on running", which is your current claim.  Please edit your question to be internally consistent.

Comment: Sorry I mean getting stuck in a loop.

Comment: Now it is giving me this System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Test.Node<T>.Data.get returned null.

In Problem.cs line 54.

Comment: Mhm, that's because you do `return up = null;` in `Result(...)`. Just return `up`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never checking if nodes are already explored, so you will likely enter an infinite loop:

```
explored.Add(next.Data.Data);
```

should be

```
if(!explored.Add(next.Data.Data)) continue;
```

But there might be other problems with the code. I would highly recommend reading Eric Lipperts article [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) since problems like this should be fairly easy to find and fix yourself with the help of a debugger. Learning how to use a debugger is an invaluable skill that will make troubleshooting much easier.

I would also recommend removing all the strings from your program. Instead you should create type representing a coordinate, i.e. a Point, or vector2Int. I would recommend making this a readonly struct, and add `ToString` overload, `IEquality<Point>` implementation, operators for addition  subtraction, equality etc. This type could then be used both for representing the state, and to represent the offsets. Such a type would be reusable for all kinds of different projects.

Comment: Thank you it solved the loop problem. However it is not outputting anything into the Console/Terminal.

Comment: @BernardJoshua Did you try debugging your program to see what it does? Because in the example the print code is commented out, and the your `Solution` method has another infinite loop. There might also be other issues that causes your program not to traverse all the nodes and exit early with no path found. So learn how to use a debugger so you can find these issues yourself.

Comment: You are right the program does not exit early even with the right input. I am going to make the changes you told me to and see how it goes. Thank You!

Comment: I managed to get it to work. Thanks for you help!